# How can I get process POSTed data in an express.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Page structure looks like:

```
index.js
 - start.js (input form customization)
 - start.ejs (input form)
 - page.js
 - page.ejs
```

I have simple form and by router.post I render it's content to be visible to user on rendered page.ejs.

start.js content:

```
router.post('/page', function(req,res))
{
    var somedata = req.body.inputForm;
    res.render('page', {somedata : somedata});
}
```

*I would like to access this data within page.js so I can process it. How would that be done?*

Comment: Is the modification of the data supposed to come before or after the `POST /page`?

Comment: Is this in the context of express or another framework?

Comment: @peteb after.@Bob_Gneu right - express.

Answer (score 1):

### Initialization

1. `mkdir SO-40876646`
2. `npm install -g express-generator`
3. `express --view=ejs .`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm start`
6. navigate to `http://localhost:3000` and validate that  the website loads (standard express website has a very simple header saying Express)

### Setting up middle ware

All middleware in Express are built from a single function call with three parameters - *request*, *response*, *next*.

- **Request** is the request object, with details from the user.
- **Response** is the response object, with details available to be sent back to the user.
- **Next** is a callback that is called when you are finished processing - providing async support to your middleware out of the box.

for our purposes, we are going to show the server side configuration for the router and our middleware to demonstrate its use.

Within our `routes/index.js` file, we create a **pageProcessor** function; this is hooked into our page router as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/page', function(req, res) {
    res.render("page", { title: 'Express', information: "undefined"})
});

router.post('/page', pageProcessor, function(req, res) {
    res.render("page", {title: 'Express', information: req.params.information})
})

function pageProcessor(req, res, next) {
    req.params.information = req.body.information.toUpperCase();

    next();
}

module.exports = router;
```

Our processing function has an opportunity to run prior to the rendering callback, to process our parameters and put them in the format we expect. In our example we are converting the information field to be uppercase and returning it, but you could use this opportunity to [log a user in](http://passportjs.org/), [validating JSON](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) or to [update a database](https://gist.github.com/clarle/3180770). The key points are that the parameters come in on req.body and [should not be assumed to be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849982/why-so-much-html-input-sanitization-necessary).

This example is rudimentary and should only be used as a stepping off point. You should look into the implementation of prominent [middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect), like [Compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) and [Cookie-Session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) for further guidance on this front.

If you would like, I have this code working and can stick it into a repo for you to pull and play with on your own.

You can read more about [authoring middleware on the expressjs website](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).

Comment: Great answer! I did use middlewares but your explanation make me do that now in a better, more proper way. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted. You may also want to read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Good luck on your web site, don't be bashful about other questions!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your

> page.ejs

file you can use **include** tag to do something like:

```
<script>    
  var data= <%= somedata  %> ;
  <% include page.js %>
</script>
```

then you can access 'data' variable in page.js as it is defined.

Comment: Interesting! I'm gonna check it asap and let you know about the results.

Comment: Are you sure you want to process it on the client side? This is frowned upon most everywhere and leaves you open to security exploits. Realistically, after the POST of your data you should be processing server side and handling all validation of the input there. Express has a great system of middleware that allows for most everything you could dream of. Most of the plugins for express use it to great effect - including input validation. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html

Comment: @Bob I agree that the way the code was written (exposing the post data directly to the client side can be  frowned upon) - but my answer is more generic. Since you can access the provided data (on render function) client side then you can access it in any <script> section there. For many reasons (like code clarity and re-usability)  you may want your client side script to be in a different js file rather then in script tag inside the ejs file.

Comment: @webmasternewbie, Did it work for you? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: This is not a good solution. If the issue is client side parsing, that should be handled up front prior to a POST. Even with multi part forms the data is not resubmitted or submitted via POST only to be processed on the client side.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It's not working :( "data is not defined".

Comment: Are you trying to use 'data' client side variable before you are doing the post? Also, try to add console.log(data) before the include statment to verify its content

Comment: After. Router.post is render a page with somedata, I display it (somadata) on this page (page.ejs) where I include page.js. In page.js I try to use console.log(data); and work on it  - with no avail. My mail is bartasb@protonmail.com lets discus there (if you wan't ofcourse) and post a solution here.

Comment: @Bob_Gneu could you elaborate more or give an example how to use middleware when I want use data from router.post in other JS file - when using express and router system? Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. Will update this when i get home and have the time. should be a couple hours from now. Ill post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. **Notice that in this case somedata is a string and needs to be quoted (in page.ejs)**

> app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //res.send('Hello World!')
  res.render('page.ejs', {somedata : 'blabla'});
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

have a **views** folder and inside it have

> page.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1>Check console to see data </h1>
<script>
    console.log('somedata is: <%= somedata %>');
    var data= '<%= somedata  %>' ;
    <% include page.js %>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and

> page.js

```
console.log('in page.js. data variable is: '+data);
```

**to Test:**

1. Run the following in command line:

   `npm install express
   npm install ejs
   node app`
2. open your web browser and navigate to 
   http://localhost:3000/
3. open development tools and select the console to see the result

Comment: thank you for your input! But as I said it's not working. Send some words on my mail I will send you info with files - you code with express router is no go.

Comment: After discussion we agreed that this is one of the possibilities to do this. So this is accepted answer.